# Sum, Avg, Max, Min, Count of NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sum

In MySQL `SELECT 2+NULL FROM tbl_name` will return `NULL`, since MySQL cannot interpret `NULL` as a number.

But why will `SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM tbl_name` not return `NULL` if just one of the values is `NULL`? The same goes for `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, etc. Since MySQL doesn't know what NULL could be, shouldn't it return NULL for all the specified functions?

Comment: Aggregate functions ignore NULL values `Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: The functions would be very useless if they would fail if there is a NULL value. MySQL in that case does not interpret it as zero, as aggregate functions will simply ignore any NULL. If thats what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question, and one that does not have a good answer.  The treatment of `NULL` in your two examples is different.

The fundamental problem is what `NULL` means.  Commonly, it is used to denote *missing* values.  However, in the ANSI standard, it stands for an *unknown* value.  I'm sure philosophers could devote tomes to the difference between "missing" and "unknown".

In a simple expression (boolean or arithmetic or scalar of another sort), ANSI defines the result of "unknown" in almost all cases where any of the operands are "unknown".  There are some exceptions:  `NULL AND FALSE` is false and `NULL IS NULL` is true, but these are rare.

For the aggregation operations, think of `SUM()` as "sum all the known values", and so on.  `SUM()` treats `NULL` values differently from `+`.  But, this behavior is also standard so that is how all databases work.

If you want a `NULL` value for an aggregation when *any* of its operands is `NULL`, then you need to use `CASE`.  I think the easiest way for a single column is:

```
(CASE WHEN COUNT(col) = COUNT(*) THEN SUM(COL) END)
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html), NULL values are ignored in the aggregate functions. Here is the direct quote from the page:

> Unless otherwise stated, group functions ignore NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

To be simple,

`2 + NULL`, probably deals with **one row** only...

Where-as `SUM( 2 and NULL )` will be with **2 different rows**. So, `NULL`s are simply ignored while you group! What ever happens with null with the same row only will be resolved into NULL again.

So

> ```
> COUNT(NULL,1) = 1 (not 2)
> MAX(NULL,1) = 1
> MIN(NULL,1) = 1
> AVG(NULL,1) = 1 (not .5)
> ```

This behaviour is same in most of the DBMS versions!