# why addition need to check null but sum not need to check null?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

select sum(a) from
Sometime when Sum, we don't need to check null value, but in add we need to check, who can tell me why? example

Sum we don't need to check null value.

```
select sum(a) from
(
select 1 a, null b from dual union 
select null, 1 b from dual
)
```

But Addition we need to check, if we don't check it will be null

```
select sum(nvl(a,0) + nvl(b,0)) from 
(
select 1 a, null b from dual union 
select null, 1 b from dual
)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Simply do `sum(a) + sum(b)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum, Avg, Max, Min, Count of NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175099/sum-avg-max-min-count-of-null-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will post a speculation that in the case of aggregate functions having the default behavior be to ignore `NULL` values agrees with the desired behavior the majority of the time.

Consider the average function `AVG` in Oracle, MySQL or most other databases.  Imagine that we have a column of values which also include a few nulls.  By having `AVG` ignore nulls we get the same result as if we had replaced those nulls with the average of all the non `NULL` values.  This would be a common technique which a statistician might employ to report an average when a few data points were unknown.  So from a statistics point of view, ignoring nulls makes sense, at least in this one very common scenario.

On the other hand, in the case of basic arithmetic, making such a presumption about nulls would not go over so well.  Consider `a + b + c` where any column might be `NULL`.  Making an assumption about what `NULL` represents could be dangerous and misleading, and could result in a DBA concluding that the value of the expression is known when in fact it is not.  In this case, we could still ignore nulls or replace them, and the `COALESCE` function (or something similar) exists, but it must be used manually.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, `null` propagates through expressions such as `A + B`.

Exceptions include aggregate functions, which generally remove `null` prior to doing the aggregation.

This means

```
SUM(a)
```

just doesn't consider rows where `a is null` while

```
SUM(a + b)
```

will discard rows where either `a is null` or `b is null` (because `a+b` is `null` if either of them is `null`).

**EDIT** Why is it that way.

Because `null` represents *missing data*. Expressions that operate on missing data cannot be evaluated and result in *missing data* again. Aggregates are obvious exceptions: they can be performed even if **some** of the data is missing.

Comment: Yes, but _why_ is this the case?  I think the OP already knows what you've posted.

Comment: I would say that aggregates are exceptions only for convenience - sum(unknown) should = unknown, logically.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp `sum(null)` is `null`. But as long as there is a single not `null` value, aggregates return a non-null value.

Comment: @MarkusWinand, I said *should*, not *does*. 1+unknown = unknown, so sum(1,unknown) "*should in an ideal world*" = unknown, not 1.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp SQL doesn't say "everything that involved `null` is `null`" but "everything that cannot be determined due to `null` is `null`". If you don't like this reasoning, it's another issue :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I agree that it is problematic that `SUM(a+b)` is not necessarily equal `SUM(a) + SUM(b)`. Nowadays, it might be better to drop the implied [`filter` clause](http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) on aggregates and let people filter it manually if needed. On the other hand, in most cases the implied `filter` clause is just right (IMHO).

Comment: Agreed the status quo is much more convenient than the alternative. c.f. the comments on this article: https://technology.amis.nl/2006/10/13/is-this-a-bug-in-analytical-functions-null-is-supposed-to-be-unequal-to-null/

Answer (score 0):

Just to add from the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035):

> All aggregate functions except COUNT(*), GROUPING, and GROUPING_ID
>   ignore nulls. You can use the NVL function in the argument to an
>   aggregate function to substitute a value for a null. COUNT and
>   REGR_COUNT never return null, but return either a number or zero. For
>   all the remaining aggregate functions, if the data set contains no
>   rows, or contains only rows with nulls as arguments to the aggregate
>   function, then the function returns null.

Ignoring nulls in aggregate functions (like SUM) is a good thing and should be expected behavior.

Comment: Aggregate functions are often used on large sets of data, doing MIN, MAX, AVG, RANK, VARIANCE, certain STAT functionality, etc.  It would get annoying very quickly when a single null blows things up.  Also, if null means "I don't know" then defaulting a null to a value like 0 for most  aggregates doesn't make sense (the average of 4,4,null,null should be 4 not 2).